# JSF 2 and Spring 3 integration

Tags: spring, jsf

In our JSF 2, spring 3 web application we have the following sets of entries in the web.xml to integrate spring and JSF

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/spring/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

And it works!

However, after going through quiet a few JSF & spring tutorials I see the need to define a **RequestContextListener** in addition to the **ContextLoaderListener**.

We have both request scope and session scope beans in our application.

Are both listeners mandatory? What is the consequence of not defining the **RequestContextListener**?

Answer (score 1):

both are not mandatory, only the ContextLoaderListener

see 
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/web-integration.html
and 
http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=81382

the RequestContextListener seems to be mandatory for Facelets

see http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextListener.html

> This listener is mainly for use with third-party servlets, e.g. the JSF FacesServlet.